# How to add spark packages to Spark R notebook on DSX?

Tags: data-science-experience

The [spark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/sparkr.html#sparkdataframe) shows how a spark package can be added:

```
sparkR.session(sparkPackages = "com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:3.0.0")
```

I believe this can only be used when initialising the session.

How can we add spark packages for SparkR using a notebook on DSX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use pixiedust package manager to install the avro package.

`pixiedust.installPackage("com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:3.0.0")`

http://datascience.ibm.com/docs/content/analyze-data/Package-Manager.html

Install it from python 1.6 kernel since pixiedust is importable in python.(Remember this is install at your spark instance level).
 Once you install it , restart the kernel and then switch to R kernel and then read the avro like this:-

`df1 <- read.df("episodes.avro", source = "com.databricks.spark.avro", header = "true")`

`head(df1)`

Complete Notebook:-

https://github.com/charles2588/bluemixsparknotebooks/raw/master/R/sparkRPackageTest.ipynb

Thanks,
Charles.