# Can't import spark within DSX environment

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, ibm-cloud, apache-spark-mllib, data-science-experience

I'm trying to import the KMeans and Vectors classes from spark.mllib. The platform is IBM Cloud (DSX) with python 3.5 and a Junyper Notebook.

I've tried:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
```

I've found several examples/tutorials with the first `import` working for the author. I've was able to confirm that the spark library itself isn't loaded in the environment. Normally, I would download the package and then `import`. But being new to VMs, I'm not sure how to make this happen.

I've also tried `pip install spark` without luck.  It throws an error that reads:

```
The following command must be run outside of the IPython shell:

    $ pip install spark

The Python package manager (pip) can only be used from outside of IPython.
Please reissue the `pip` command in a separate terminal or command prompt.
```

But this is in a VM where I don't see the ability to externally access the CLI.

I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45355711/dsx-python-import-error-undefined-symbol-pyunicodeucs2-asutf8string), but I don't think I have a mismatch problem -- the issue on importing into DSX is covered but I can't quite interpret it for my situation.

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42279520/how-to-add-spark-packages-to-spark-r-notebook-on-dsx) is the actual issue I'm having but it is for sparkR and not python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use Scala code in a Python notebook.

To get the spark session:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

This will print the version of Spark:

```
spark.version
```

To import the ML libraries:

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans
from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeansModel
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
```

Note: This uses the spark.ml package. The spark.mllib package is the RDD-based library and is currently in maintenance mode. The primary ML library is now spark.ml (DataFrame-based).

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html

Comment: This was the push I needed.  I discovered that you'll still need to install pyspark with `!pip install --user pyspark` (the ! giving access at the jupyter level).  I noticed that both `mllib` and `ml` work, just with different syntax - but will recode to `ml`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

DSX environments don't have Spark. When you create a new notebook, you have to decide whether it runs in one of the new environments, without Spark, or in the Spark backend.